# MongoDB iterating cursor using python

Tags: python, json, mongodb, document, database-cursor

I am trying to extract some data from a mongodatabase. My collection is structured in this way:

_id:5d306db32e98f83520ae90b7
entity_id:"360803e052b511e3bc11180373d69d01"
entity_type_name_item:"TEST"
entity_name_item:"Sea"
data:"{"json"}"
file_type:"list"
entity_name:"000001"

I need to extract the json file in "data" and do some operation. The code is working but is really, really slow when I try to loop through the cursor:

```
    for entity in entity_list:
       cursor = db[coll_name].find({'entity_id':entity})

       for document in cursor:
           jdata = json.loads(document['data'])
```

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried to profile your code?  It is not clear what is slow here, getting the data or parsing the json.  If json parsing is slow, try a faster json parser (https://pypi.org/project/ujson/).

If mongo is slow, try to only fetch what you need using the `projection` params. https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find .  In addition, you can fetch all the entities in one query using the `$in` opetator (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) `db[coll_name].find({'entity_id': {'$in': entity_list}})`

Answer (score 1):

I believe that losing speed occurs in part where you make the query.

You can speed up this part using:

```
find({'entity_id': {'$in': entity_list}})
```